# How to give Website link in WebView in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android-studio

In my app, I want to give the link in WebView. How to give it?
My Link is "http://www.google.com" using Android Studio and Java. Here my link is a "http" link which means external link. Ideas are appreciated!!!

Comment: You should at least comment the actual url for your app what if the problem is with the website not your Android Code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Something like this?

```
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView();
    }
    private void webView(){
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //Handling Page Navigation
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        //Load a URL on WebView
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. When using your code, it shows error near `MyWebViewClient()` like `Cannot resolve symbol MyWebViewClient()`

Comment: Thanks for your time... I have some other option.. will post shortly...

Answer (score 0):

You have to to it at the activity/fragment.

It depends on how you want to load the URL, 
[here you have all the documentation about that](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadUrl(java.lang.String))

At any case, the simplest code would be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

And if you want to use the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Add the [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) permission to your manifest file.
**You have to add this line:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="es.raulprieto.webviewtry">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
```

Comment: Hi.. Website is not opening instead of that it shows error like `Webpage not available`

Comment: Are you still having trouble with it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what do you want to do with that WebView but i recommend you to use the mobiles web browser instead of a WebView in your app.

Activities in Android are independent Android components and to connect them, you use the object Intent. This way you can create a new activity inside your app or you can start third party activity. In this case, the web browser.Try this code and tell me if this solves your problem

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://google.com");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And make sure you always type the https:// or http:// every time you use an URL.

Comment: Hi... your code redirecting me to mobile's web browser. But i want to open the website in my app itself. Kindly read the query properly and after that post your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I posted this in case you didnt know this could be done. Just for helping :D